# How to perform mathematical operation on Long and BigInt in scala in spark-sql

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, bigdata

I have two values of different type as shown below in spark-sql

```
scala> val ageSum = df.agg(sum("age"))
ageSum: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [sum(age): bigint]
scala> val totalEntries = df.count();
scala> totalEntries
res37: Long = 45211
```

First value is coming from aggregate function on data frame and second is coming from total count function on data frame. Both are having different types as ageSum is bigInt and totalEntries is Long. I want to perform mathematical operation on it. Mean = ageSum/totalEntries

```
scala> val mean = ageSum/totalEntries
<console>:31: error: value / is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame val mean = ageSum/totalEntries
```

I also tried to convert to ageSum to long type but not able to do so

```
scala> val ageSum = ageSum.longValue
<console>:29: error: recursive value ageSum needs type
val ageSum = ageSum.longValues
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*ageSum* is a data frame, you need to extract the value from it. One option would be to use *first()* to get the value as a *Row* and then extract the value from the row:

```
ageSum.first().getAs[Long](0)/totalEntries
// res6: Long = 2
```

If you need a more exact value, you can use `toDouble` to convert before division:

```
ageSum.first().getAs[Long](0).toDouble/totalEntries
// res9: Double = 2.5
```

---

Or you can make the result another column of your ageSum:

```
ageSum.withColumn("mean", $"sum(age)"/totalEntries).show
+--------+----+
|sum(age)|mean|
+--------+----+
|      10| 2.5|
+--------+----+
```

---

```
val df = Seq(1,2,3,4).toDF("age")
```

Comment: This works as charm.Thank you. I am struggling to find documentation related to operations supported by Data Frames. Do you know any good article to read for this thing?

Comment: You can check [this website](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/api/scala/#package). Not all functions listed under data frame though. Don't have better resources currently.